# How to turn off Firefox Android autocomplete ads?

Tags: firefox-for-android

On a previous version of Firefox for Android, I was able to turn off the address bar ads.  By address bar ads, I mean that, e.g., if I type in "al" into the address bar, the site "allrecipes.com" pops up.

I've not been to this site.  I don't want this site recommended.  Mostly, I don't want this site recommended, because it seems to take precedence in the autocomplete over a site that I *do* go to that starts with "al".  I want *that* site to be recommended.

How do I turn off the address bar ads in the latest Firefox for Android (v97)? (but still keep autocomplete for my browsing history)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible without turning off the suggestions feature alltogether which would obviously hide suggestions based on history too.